# Can neo4j be used with NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, neo4j

I have just found out about the existence of graph databases and neo4j and was wandering if there was a way to use it within NetBeans somehow in the way Apache Derby is used. I'm sorry if this is a very stupid question, I've just begun learning about databases and am far from knowing my way around. I can most definitely look for a way to do this on my own, but if a more experienced person can share a tip about this, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Can you be more specific? i.e. Do you want to set it up in the services tab? Or do you just want to write code that accesses or starts an Neo4j instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Neo4j either as part of your java application or as standalone server, see:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials.html